# I/O request issue in using Amazon EBS with microinstance

Tags: amazon-ebs

I am using microinstance with EBS but because of lots of I/O request cost of using ebs becomes big issue for us.

Can you suggest me any ways of using ebs volume with less I/O requests.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use ebs supported instance we get charged for every hardisk reads/writes.
We can use caching to avoid I/O request and save 80% of money.

Answer (score 0):

EBS is not exactly fast compared to a local disk array or a good SAN.

One can get a near linear performance increase by striping multiple EBS volumes into a software RAID configuration, up to a point. Last time I measured you start to get diminishing returns at 4 EBS volumes for a small instance or 8 for a large instance. Never measured a micro instance.

Adding EBS volumes is not free but at least that gives you an option.